# Как выбрать случайные 10 записей из базы MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, выборка

Использую для выборки вот такую конструкцию:

```
$result_link_check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vk_likes WHERE country='0' AND sex='0' AND user_age_from='0' AND user_age_to='100' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10 ");
```

Слышал, что `RAND()` очень грузит сервер, если база большая. Интересует, есть ли вариант попроще, чтобы быстрее работал?

Answer (score 3):

Подборку вариантов приведу:

1. Большого смысла собственно нет заморачиваться, если таблица на тысячу записей и запросы идут далеко не пачками.
2. Доп. таблица - random_seed, содержащая поля id и random_seed, заполняемая случайными числами, на данную колонку добавляется индекс, также индекс добавляется на колонку, по которой будет происходить выборка.

   SELECT u1.* FROM users u1, random_seed rs WHERE u1.role_id=5 AND u1.id=(rs.id+random_from_php) ORDER BY rs.random_seed LIMIT 10
3. Переносим логику на приложение (в случае последовательных ID без разрывов):

   SELECT MAX(id) FROM random;
   // generate random id in application
   SELECT name FROM random WHERE id =
4. Производится подготовительная операция и тем же запросом выборка из t_random, первый подзапрос имитирует нумерацию строк:

   ```
   SELECT  rnd_id, rnd_value FROM (
       SELECT  @cnt := COUNT(*) + 1, @lim := 10
           FROM t_random
   ) vars 
   STRAIGHT_JOIN
   (
   SELECT  r.*, @lim := @lim - 1
       FROM    t_random r
       WHERE   (@cnt := @cnt - 1)
           AND RAND(20090301) < @lim / @cnt
   ) i
   ```
5. В случае со столбцом ID с автоинкрементом, есть удаленные строки. Запрашивается 50 строк "про запас", лимит строк - 10, быстро при любых размерах таблицы. Explain и индексы делать не забываем.

```
SELECT @min := MIN(id),
               @max := MAX(id)
FROM RandTest;


SELECT a.*
FROM RandTest a
JOIN
  (SELECT id
   FROM
     (SELECT id
      FROM
        (SELECT @min + (@max - @min + 1 - 5) * RAND() AS START
         FROM DUAL) AS init
      JOIN RandTest y
      WHERE y.id > init.
        START
      ORDER BY y.id LIMIT 50 -- Inflated to deal with gaps
 ) z
   ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10 -- number of rows desired
 ) r ON a.id = r.id;
```

источники:
http://habrahabr.ru/post/207096/
http://explainextended.com/2009/03/01/selecting-random-rows/
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random

Comment: Ответы _там_ хорошие. Но у нас на СО просто ссылки делать не рекомендуется, потому как ссылки со временем могут перестать работать, а ответы на СО должны жить вечно

Comment: Понял. исправляюсь.